# Excel Macro - True/ False VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

So I am a complete beginner when it comes to this sort of thing. So, I have recorded a macro that does find and replace on everything. I stepped into the code to see what it looked like and I had a play with the true and false elements however I have no idea what changing the code to true does as it appears to do the same when I run the macro.

```
Cells.Replace What:="name", Replacement:="location", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=True, _
ReplaceFormat:=True
```

Comment: You can see some more detail on the [Microsoft MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx).  Does that help? Or are you still unsure?  Obviously if you do `MatchCase:=False`, the replace won't search for an exact case match.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) is clear for `MatchCase\Byte` but ignores the other two boolean properties.

If the `SearchFormat`/`ReplaceFormat` values are `True` the `Replace` function will pay attention to what is set in the `Application.FindFormat` & `Application.ReplaceFormat` properties, allowing you to conduct search and replace based on the format of a cell, i.e. Red text in a cell containing "woof"

Answer (score 0):

Search format distinguishes between cell formats (i.e: number vs percentage, cell fills etc...). In this case if you search for a standard no formatted cell containing "50%". If you have a percentage formatted cell that is bright purple that says 50% in your sheet, it should not find it>

MatchCase is weather or not capitals matter. so MatchCase:= true will not find "TEST CELL" if you search for "test cell".